# It claims to be a Kramer

Tags: electric-guitar

all.  I have acquired this weird guitar.  It has a Kramer plate on the back with a serial and no other identifying marks.  I have checked everywhere: under all the plates, behind the pickups, under the tremolo, and inside the neck joint.  I removed the tremolo, but it is a Floyd Rose II.  I would not be suspicious except

1. Kramers are notoriously difficult.  The serials are inconsistent and so are the productions.
2. It looks like Vanguard, but it has the jack behind the top fin instead of the bottom.  It also looks like a Jackson RR.
3. The neck doesn't have any logo on it, but looks a lot like a Jackson... it's reverse headstock with sharp angles (Kramer is curved) and has sharkfin inlays.  I can't seem to find any Kramer examples of this.

**Can anybody tell me for sure if this is a Kramer?  Any info would be great.**

[image: BodyFront]

[image: HeadStock]

[image: NeckPlate]

[image: FinJack]

[image: BockBack]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered only by expert examination, which is difficult without having the instrument in person.

Comment: I thought this was the place to go for access to other's expertise.  I trust this public forum/community more than some random expert I might find locally.  I am happy to take more pictures or provide more info if it will help.

Comment: No ill will, and I've certainly enjoyed looking at a very unique guitar, but to be honest I'd trust a "real person" more than an online community anyway. Someone who could answer this might not even live near you, but surely there's a Kramer specialist out there somewhere.

Comment: @AndyBonner maybe there is one on here who might have some info.  In any case, I wouldn't be so quick to close this.  Your last comment does come across as ill will toward this community.  I would love to hear what this community has to say about this, as long they are interested.  Besides, it's been voted up twice already.   It sounds like at least 2 other people are interested in it.

Comment: Instrument identification questions are explicitly off topic here. Please see https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The main issue, as the good @Doktor mentions, is simply that questions like this don't line up well with the site's intent. If, as I have, you find it confusing, you can look through the Meta part of the site for conversations [like this one](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/do-we-still-agree-that-identification-of-types-of-instrument-is-on-topic-should). Mainly, it boils down to a philosophy of building a "body of reference," of answers that future people with the same question might come across and benefit from, ...

Comment: ... as opposed to a "help desk" where individuals get individually-applicable answers. It's true that there's disagreement with this philosophy, and that users' behaviors often reinforce the "help desk" idea, but that's the thinking behind it. Meanwhile, it's still true that someone who examines and authenticates instruments for a living is the best person to figure out its history, and the best way to do it is in-person. ...

Comment: There aren't a lot of regularly active members here, and I'm guessing anyone who might be able to help would have by now. You're welcome to bring it up in [the chat channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) though—there are no rules about "on-topic" there.

Comment: Frankly, I think I'm done here.  This is ridiculous.  I have never been on a stack exchange with so many hacky rules.  This is the second question I asked that was up-voted and then closed for being off-topic.  Learning about equipment and instruments (history, etc.) should not be considered off-topic in a music site.

Comment: @rfportilla - This is not "a music site" - it has a specific scope with very simple restrictions. if you go and read that page you will see what is on topic. You may not agree with that, but that is the current scope that has been agreed on by the community over time. There are a million other sites online, and some may fit what you need better - so you should use them for questions that are outside our scope.